# 一番下のむす子 Translation

Tags: translation, meaning

I have the following sentence that I have to translate for my homework.

> 今、ちょうど**一番下のむす子**が、昼寝をしているところです。

I am having trouble with the `一番下のむす子` part. I think might mean "youngest son" (number 1 low's son), but I am not sure.

> Right now ... is just in the midst of taking a nap.

Can anyone help me understand this sequence? Thank you.

**Also**, out of curiosity, what is the romaji for the 昼寝? hirone or chuune?

Comment: Think: 年下 (toshishita).

Comment: First Google hit for 昼寝: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%BC%E5%AF%9D   You can use kanji in the search engine. Wink!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you suspect, 一番下の息子 means youngest son. (一番上の子供 would be oldest child.) You also seem to understand the rest of the sentence just fine.

昼寝 is ひるね, as any dictionary look-up would confirm. Mixed 音読み and 訓読み readings are quite rare, so your first guess should be ひるね or ちゅうしん.

Comment: I was confused because Google is usually good at short phrases. Do you know what the romaji for the "nap" kanji is?

Comment: I would caution against using Google Translate as a way to solve your translation homework. We see many Google Translate results here, but even simple sentences are often bad translations.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use it for full translations. It's just usually pretty good at short stuff.

Comment: @RachelG. You can't trust it, even with short phrases.  Besides, you'll need to start using a real dictionary at some point to look up things like the reading of 昼寝.