# How do you translate: 一番頭がいい

Tags: meaning

The full sentence is: 彼はクラスで一番頭がいいと勘違いしている。

The part I'm not understanding is:
一番頭がいい

Comment: It means "the most intelligent".

Comment: can you provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Recommended search: http://jisho.org/search/%E9%A0%AD%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84

Comment: Please explain what parts you understand, also what parts of 一番頭がいい you may understand.

Comment: to my english brain it reads like: number one head good, and that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I sort of understand now, I need to parse that as 一番・頭がいい

Comment: Maybe try クラスで一番: Number one in the class 頭が良い: for having a good head (intelligence)

Comment: that makes more sense, ありがとうございます。

Comment: In its current form the question is likely to be closed. If you wish to add your comments to your question, please do so by editing the question. You can also see e.g. [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/%e4%b8%80%e7%95%aa%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%82%80%e3%81%99%e5%ad%90-translation?rq=1) for this use of 一番, which doesn't really translate to "number one" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The comment section has sorted this out, but just to summarize the whole thing,)

「頭がいい」 is an idiom (慣用句) that means bright/intelligent. 「一番」 is literally number one, and from there it means best/top/most/first. 一番 is strictly speaking a noun, so from that perspective this should be 一番に頭がいい by inserting a particle, but this particle often gets dropped, and 一番 can work like an adjective, just like "best."

So the whole sentence translates to "He wrongly thinks he is the brightest in this class."

Answer (score 0):

「[一番]{いちばん}X」, with X an adjective, means "the most X" (literally, "the first [in a ranked list] X").

This is a casual (though polite) way to say this, and the formal way is 「[最]{もっと}もX」. Besides, there are adjectives that are already superlatives, that you might come across with:

> [最高]{さいこう}
>   the highest
>   [最新]{さいしん}
>   the newest
>   [最適]{さいてき}
>   the best, the most appropriate

These adjective are actually rather frequent, so you might want to give it a look.